# Swift Dictionary is not printing key values

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am new to swift programming. I have written the following code for iterating and printing dictionary

```
var items_price = [
"milk": 1 ,
"bread" : 3,
"egg" : 2
]

for (myKey, myValue) in items_price {
      println ("\(myKey) costs : \(myValue)")
}
```

This code is not printing the result as "milk costs: 1" ,etc. What is wrong?

Comment: Code is right ! The function seems to be not called.. We need more code to help you ;) Are you using the playground ?

Comment: Well this is the entire code. In the end it does say (3 times). But does not print the result :-(

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I tested it on swiftstub.com

Comment: Are you using playground ?

Comment: @thedjnivek Yes OP is using playground, check tag

Comment: Well, so press the +, as @Kirsteins says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`println` statements are printed in timeline of playgrounds. Press the "+" in the circle at the end of print statement line.
[image]

Comment: sorry being new to swift I am unable to understand this

Comment: I tihnk this will help you understand OP https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vogFSIxprUo